# Smooth svg polyline points animation to create dynamic financial stock chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to create a dynamic financial stock linear chart using svg polyline.
I was able to update the chart by adding new coordinates after every one second. But I want it to animate to each coordinates instead of jumping to the new coordinates after one second

i have tried using jquery keyframes library but the animation was not what i wanted. I want the polyline to animate from the initial coordinate to the new coordinate

```
$.keyframe.define([{
name: 'myfirst',
  from: {
    'stroke-dashoffset': '1000'
  },
  to: {
    'stroke-dashoffset': '0'
  }

  }]);
 $("#path").css({"stroke-dasharray":'1000',"stroke-dashoffset":'1000'});

 $("#path").playKeyframe({
   name: 'myfirst',
     duration: '5s',
timingFunction: 'linear',
iterationCount: '1'


 });
```

HTML

```
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1000px" height="600px" class="logo-outline" viewBox="0 0 1000 600" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 600" xml:space="preserve">
<polyline id="path" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />

</svg></body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     var x = 0;
     var y1 = 0;
     var y2 = 0;
     var y = 0;
     var point = 0+","+Math.round(Math.random()*1000);

     function upD() {
        x+=40;
        y2 = y1;
        y1=y;
        y = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
        point+=" "+x+","+y;
        document.getElementById('path').setAttribute('points',point);
        // jquery keyframe library
     $.keyframe.define([{
        name: 'myfirst',
        from: {
            'stroke-dashoffset': '80%'
        },
        to: {
           'stroke-dashoffset': '0'
        }

    }]);
    $("#path").css({"stroke-dasharray":'100%',"stroke-dashoffset":'100%'});

    $("#path").playKeyframe({
        name: 'myfirst',
        duration: '5s',
     timingFunction: 'linear',
          iterationCount: '1'


   });
   }
     window.setInterval(upD,3000);

  });
```

I'm aiming to make a chart with polyline animation as that of olymp trade, or binarycent trade chart or something similar like a tick chart

Answer (score 1):

Normally this type of animation is done in CSS by animating the [stroke-dashoffset property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dashoffset/)

First you need to calculate the length of your path. In this case you can get the length of the polyline using `path.getTotalLength()`. This should be also the initial value for `#path{stroke-dasharray: 1697.5px;}` This means that the polyline has dashes and gaps of equal length: 1697.5px . Also the `stroke-dashoffset` is 1697.5px;` This means that the path is hidden since gap between the dashes is covering the whole polyline.

The @keyframes animation begins animating the stroke-dashoffset from 1697.5px to 0, till the dash is covering the whole path.

I hope this is what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}

#path{
  stroke-dasharray: 1697.5px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1697.5px;
  animation:test 6.5s forwards
}

@keyframes test {   
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1697.5px;}   
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}  
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1000px" height="600px" class="logo-outline" viewBox="0 0 1000 600" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 600" xml:space="preserve">
<polyline id="path" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" points="0,518 40,68 80,2 120,63 160,17 200,42 240,75 280,99 320,44 360,59 400,34 440,28 480,56 520,68 560,54 600,26 640,74 680,78 720,27 760,9 800,45 840,72 880,73 920,70 960,13 1000,35"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the points in the outline are added by javascript. And what I want is when the javascript append a new coordinates I want the polyline to animate to that new coordinate instead just show when the javascript function is called.

Comment: I've been looking for how to create a progressive reveal animation for polyline and your answer was really helpful. In particular, the relationship between `getTotalLength()` and properties `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`. Thank you very much!